# Call subclass's static method from parent class's non-static method

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, static-methods

Suppose I have the following simple code:

```
class A {

    protected int someMethod() {
        return staticMethod();
    }

    private static int staticMethod() {
        return 10;
    }

}


class B extends A {

    protected int someMethod() {
        return super.someMethod();
    }

    public static int staticMethod() {
        return 20;
    }

}

class TestX {

    private void main() {

        B b = new B();

        int finalValue =b.someMethod();

    }
}
```

In the above code, when `b.someMethod()` is executed, it ends up calling `A`'s version of `staticMethod()`. But I thought static methods are called based on the type of reference of the main object. Since the object on which `someMethod()` is called is of type `B`, shouldn't `B`'s version of `staticMethod()` be called even when `A`'s `someMethod()` is called (because of the line `return super.someMethod();`) ?

Given the above code, is there a way I can make `B`'s `staticMethod()` get executed so that 20 is returned instead of 10 ?

I found a similar question but the idea suggested in it isn't relevant to me I think:

[Calling subclass's static method from parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674582/calling-subclasss-static-method-from-parent-class)

Comment: I don't think there's any typo. Can you copy paste the line on which you think there's a typo ?

Comment: [Your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334849/subclasss-static-method-not-being-called-from-parent-classs-non-static-method) got closed as duplicate, no reason to just recreate the same question.,

Comment: @tkausl, this question is different from my last one. If you read, I'm asking a different thing here. I would appreciate if you can re-open my question.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That won't be enough. The super implementation of `someMethod` is trying to invoke the `static` method. That wouldn't compile.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, it will be enough, someMethod is accessible by both this and super references in the child, isn't it?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Sorry, I misread. Their intention is to get 20. Whether you remove the hiding method in the subclass or not, they'll still get 10.