# Passing an instance of a class in Groovy using generics

Tags: grails, generics, groovy, controller

Grails: 2.4.4
Groovy: 2.4.1
Java  : 1.8u40

Windows 7

I am trying to make a generics based controller that members of my team can extend as needed.

Having just getting this issue solved in Groovy with generics ( [Why doesn't this generic usage work in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867574/why-doesnt-this-generic-usage-work-in-groovy))

I am now running into the following issue in a Grails controller trying to pass an instance of the class.

The TeamCotroller:

```
class TeamController extends BaseController<Team> {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    TeamController() {
        super(Team)
    }

    /*
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Team.list(params), model:[teamInstanceCount: Team.count()]
    }
    */
    /*
    def show(Team teamInstance) {
       respond teamInstance
    }
    */
    /*
    def create() {
        respond new Team(params)
    }
    */

    /* More default CRUD methods cut out for now */
}
```

The Generic Controller:
    class BaseController {

```
    private final Class<T> clazz

    BaseController(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz
    }

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond clazz.list(params), model:[instanceCount: clazz.count()]
    }

    // TODO: Figure this out
    def show(Team instance) {
        respond instance
    }
}
```

In the `show(Team instance)` method, I have replaced `Team` with `Class<T>` and `T` in an attempt to get the instance being passed to it by Grails/Groovy but it doesn't even seem to be hitting the method at all when I run in debug mode. What does one need to do in order to get the instance being passed to the controller?

--edit-- Adding Exception
 `2015-03-06 15:56:36,400 [http-bio-8090-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /test-list/team/show/1
No such property: instance for class: TeamController. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: instance for class: TeamController`

-- Edit -- Adding controller code

Comment: Can you post the code for your `TeamController` also?

Comment: Added the TeamController code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work when passing the instance directly into the parameters of the method, but it does work as expected when using the `id` parameter, like so:

#### grails-app/controllers/BaseController.groovy

```
abstract class BaseController<T> {

  private final Class<T> clazz

  BaseController() {}

  BaseController(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz
  }

  def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond clazz.list(params), model:[instanceCount: clazz.count()]
  }

  def show(Long id) {
    def instance = clazz.get(id)
    respond instance
  }
}
```

#### grails-app/controllers/TeamController.groovy

```
class TeamController extends BaseController<Team> {

    TeamController() {
        super(Team)
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to access the `/team/show/1.?{format}` endpoint without an issue.

I setup an example project [here](https://github.com/caseyscarborough/stackoverflow_28908151) to demonstrate.

Comment: This did indeed work.  Thank you very much.  I am now working on incorporating this on the rest of the methods.