# How do I use Enum's static functions inside a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, enums

```
public class EnumFromInt<TEnum extends Enum<TEnum>> {

    private static TEnum[] _values;

    private static TEnum[] GetValues() {
        if (_values != null)
        {
            return _values;
        }

        _values = TEnum.values();
        return _values;
    }
}
```

Above, there are two instances of "**cannot be referenced from a static context**". They seem separate, so I'll treat them as different problems. I'd like to understand both.

- `TEnum[]` -  Why? It's an array of whatever type TEnum is. (Well, that's what I'd like it to be)
- `TEnum.values()` - TEnum is declared to be of type Enum, so shouldn't I be able to use the static functions that belong to all enums?

Comment: Class-level generics only apply to instances in Java, so you can't reference them in a static context. And you can't call static methods on a generic type. I don't know the reasoning behind the latter, but here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6512179/1553851

Comment: Your two bullet points are inconsistent with each other about the nature of `TEnum`.  The first is more correct with its "whatever type TEnum is".  The second seems to suppose that `TEnum` is an object "declared to be *of* type Enum" (emphasis added), which it is not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But it is: `TEnum extends Enum<TEnum>`

Comment: With respect to the first bullet point, see [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java).

Comment: No, @shmosel, `TEnum` is a type parameter, representing a type.  That it is declared with a bound does not make it an object or the identifier of an object.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see, I misread your comment. Still, given that `TEnum` represents a type, it's reasonable to expect to be able to call a static method on said type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger As far as generic type arrays are concerned, `TEnum[]` is a perfectly valid type in a non-static context.

Comment: You are right, @shmosel.

Comment: Thank you. The above discussion is helpful.

Comment: Please just call the generic type `T` and not `TEnum`. TEnum looks like a normal type, not a generic type. If you use `T' it is clear that you mean the generic type.

Comment: @NickL I want the 'extends' constraint to be obvious to maintenance coders.

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for the Java Generic type naming convention. "Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name."

Comment: I don't really see the point of this code. What is the end goal? (The hypothetical) `MyEnum[] vals = EnumFromInt<MyEnum>.GetValues()`? Why not just use `MyEnum[] vals = MyEnum.values()` directly then?

Comment: The sample above is incomplete. We have a C++ layer that is called by Java. Code gen creates enum code in both languages. Getting a Java enum from an int (the C++ enum) is common enough that I'd like to generalize it. _values() is slightly expensive due to data copying, so I'd like to cache it. Any part of our Java code might want to do such a conversion, so I'd like the entry point to be static.

Comment: The missing function is:
public static TEnum FromInt(int codeGenInt) {
        return GetValues()[codeGenInt];
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I've got an idea what you want to do.

In that case you would need to pass the enum's class and call `getEnumConstants`:

```
class EnumFromInt {

    private static final Map<Class<?>, Object[]> _values = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <TEnum extends Enum<TEnum>> TEnum[] getValues(Class<TEnum> cls) {
        return (TEnum[]) _values.computeIfAbsent(cls, Class::getEnumConstants);
    }
}
```

You'd also have to use a `Map`, since a field could only store 1 array of values. There's no way to enforce that the type of the key correspond to the type of the value, so you need to store the value arrays as `Object[]` and use an unchecked cast later when retrieving them.