# How to call a method returning generic type correctly (Java)?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method which has generic type to return. I would like to call it properly in order to return compilation error in case the returning type, I use it for, does not comply the boundaries this way avoiding run-time errors (vs compilation) and use all the power of Java generic types.

```
public <T extends IDeserializable> T restoreObject(byte[] objectArray) {

    T object = T.getDeserialized(objectArray);
    
    return object;
}
```

However, calling it this way

```
File ret = restoreObject(new byte[] {1,2,3});
```

would not produce compilation error and therefore the error will be generated at runtime only. The File type does not implement IDeserializable, however java does not generate compilation error.

```
public interface IDeserializable {
        public static <T> T getDeserialized(byte[] data) {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: line 2 does not compile: `T.getDeserialized(objectArray);` is not valid java.

Comment: And java cannot know this won't succeed because you might have a class defined `class Something extends File implements IDeserializable` which would make the assignment work.

Comment: No, it does not compile since `T` does not exist as a type or instance, you cannot do anything with T other than cast to it. And if it would exist it would be type, not an instance that implements a method or conforms to anything.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. It is static in the interface. Updated the interface in the question.

Comment: But now you are once again out of luck in terms of what java can do. The static method in that interface cannot be overriden an will forever remain `return null` or whatever other specific body you have in there. But a class `A implements IDeserializable` cannot have a different body / logic compared to `B implements IDeserializable` which renders the method completely useless for your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

- Calling static methods on type parameters does not work the way you may think it does ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512179/calling-a-static-method-using-generic-type) is a question about that).
- In any case, `getDeserialized` is an instance method, not a static method, so you can't do `T.getDeserialized(objectArray)`.
- <s>The compiler cannot infer `T` just like that.</s> @luk2302 has corrected me - `T` will be inferred as the type of whatever you're assigning the result to.

You need to give `restoreObject` an argument of type `T` so that the compiler can infer `T` and so that you can call the `getDeserialized` method:

```
public <T extends IDeserializable> T restoreObject(byte[] objectArray, T t) {
    return t.getDeserialized(objectArray);
}
```

However, I suspect you meant `getDeserialized` to be a static method. Unfortunately, you cannot do that, because static methods don't get overriden. You can, however, make `restoreObject` take a `Function` parameter:

```
public <T extends IDeserializable> T restoreObject(byte[] objectArray, Function<byte[], T> deserialize) {
    return deserialize.apply(objectArray);
}
```

Then you can use a lambda or method reference for the `deserialize` argument.

---

You can also use [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html), but @daniu has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636847/how-to-call-a-method-returning-generic-type-correctly-java/64636930?noredirect=1#comment114288166_64636930) that `Serializable` will be removed some time in the future and is not a good idea. There are tons of libraries out there already so you don't have to handle the serialization/deserialization yourself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239280/which-is-the-best-alternative-for-java-serialization) are some alternatives for serialization in Java. Java also has its own XML API if you don't want to use outside libraries.

Comment: Correct except for the last point, the compiler *can* "infer" `T`, it will just be exactly the type you write on the left hand side of the assignment.

Comment: It's kind of anachronistic to recommend using `Serializable`, [it's been called a "horrible mistake" by Oracle itself](https://m.slashdot.org/story/341416) and they plan to remove it. Avoid if possible.

Comment: @daniu Oh, I didn't know that, I'm not in the loop about these things. I've added a link to a question about alternatives now, is that better?

Answer (score 0):

This gets obvious really fast, if you could *imagine* a theoretical type `Weirdo` that could do:

```
 class Weird extends File implements IDeserializable
```

And then:

```
static <T> T getDeserialized(byte[] data) {
        return new Weirdo();
}
```

Or even simpler (since the cast to a type parameter can't be enforced):

```
 static <T> T getDeserialized(byte[] data) {
      return (T) "";
 }
```

You can see that the problem is in your `getDeserialized` to begin with and callers have to trust you. But if you think why *static* methods exist in interfaces (their main purpose is to return an *instance* of the interface), then you are abusing these methods. What is the point in making it `static` if no one can override it? You might want to rethink what you are trying to do.

But anyway, if you replace that with a `class` - you *will* get a compile time error (I will let you figure out why, though):

```
public static class IDeserializable {

    static <T> T getDeserialized(byte[] data) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```